# gulp-wiredep to replace path

Tags: django, gulp, wiredep

for django, i am trying to insert a relative path ..

the wiredep section of my older grunt file looked like this

```
wiredep: {
      dashboard: {
        src: '<%= backOffice.dashboard %>/base.html',
        exclude: ['/selectize/', '/sifter/', '/microplugin/'],
        ignorePath: '../../static/',
        fileTypes: {
          html: {
            replace: {
              js: '<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}"></script>',
              css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}" />'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

i am trying to do the same with my wiredep.js for gulp task and this is what it looks like

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

  gulp.src('src/{app,components}/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: 'src/bower_components'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));

  gulp.src('../../templates/backoffice/__base.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      fileTypes: {
        html: {
          replace: {
            js: '<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}"></script>',
            css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}" />'
          }
        }
      }
    }));
```

but this isn't working, can anybody help?

Comment: So you trying to generate js-file via django, that nodejs will run later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer, must include the gulp.dest for the file to be created.

```
gulp.src('../../templates/backoffice/__base.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      ignorePath: '../../static/',
      fileTypes: {
        html: {
          replace: {
            js: '<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}"></script>',
            css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{filePath}}" />'
          }
        }
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../templates/backoffice'));
```